# How to write procedure which will loop the input line N times in TCL

Tags: for-loop, tcl, proc

looking for what could be the "proc_of_for_loop"

`puts $fp [proc_of_for_loop abc[$i] 5]`

output should be like,

```
abc0
abc1
abc2
abc3
abc4
abc5
```

Answer (score 2):

The natural way of doing that in Tcl would be this:

```
proc n_range {varName from to body} {
    upvar 1 $varName var
    for {set var $from} {$var <= $to} {incr var} {
        uplevel 1 $body
    }
}

n_range i 0 5 {
    puts $fp "abc$i"
}
```

The `upvar` and `uplevel` commands are a major part of the secret sauce of Tcl; they let you create your own control constructs in very little code.

Comment: You could go with things to apply substitutions many times and collect the result, but that's actually more complicated. This really is much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the "substitute and collect" approach.  Less general than Donal's solution, but closer to what's requested, and not significantly more complicated IMHO:

```
proc string_for {string count} {
    for {set i 1} {$i <= count} {incr i} {
        append result [subst $string]
    }
    return $result
}

puts $fp [string_for {abc$i\n} 5]
```